# SimpleDateFormat month name with uppercase

Tags: java, jasper-reports

How to change the month name to uppercase. 
Anyone know about this?

This is my example condition:

```
(new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy")).format($P{date_start})
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `.toUpperCase()` , as follows:

```
(new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy")).format($P{date_start}).toString().toUpperCase()
```